# Remember Me button in android app

Tags: javascript, android, plugins, authentication, sharedpreferences

I have recently created a new plugin for an android app I've been working on. This plugin requires the use of a remember me function that I cant seem to get working properly. Within my code I've designated the use of shared properties at the top and the string pass.

```
View thisScreensView = null;

String errormessage = "";
String errormessageTextColor = "";
String errormessageText = "";
String rememberTextText = "";
String rememberTextTextColor = "";
String voucherTextfieldPlaceholder = "";
String voucherTextfieldSecureTextEntry = "";
boolean voucherTextfieldSecureTextEntryBool = false;
String iphoneImage = "";
String ipadImage = "";
String errormessageInvalid = "";
String errormessageRemember = "";

private TextView errormessageTextView = null;
private EditText voucherTextfieldEditText = null;
private ImageView imageView = null;
private Button submitButton = null;
private Switch rememberSwitch = null;

private Drawable myHeaderImageDrawable = null;
private String alphaImage = "", pass;
private static BT_item screenObjectToLoad = null;
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
```

I have it assigning the variable pass into the designated text box with this code:

```
voucherTextfieldEditText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    rememberSwitch = (Switch) thisScreensView.findViewById(R.id.rememberSwitch);
    // set the switch to ON
    rememberSwitch.setText(errormessageRemember);
    rememberSwitch.setChecked(true);
    // attach a listener to check for changes in state
    rememberSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            if (isChecked) {
                BT_debugger.showIt(fragmentName + ":rememberSwitch is ON");
                // switchStatus.setText("Switch is currently ON");

                //voucherTextfieldEditText.setText(pref.getString(pass, null));

            } else {
                BT_debugger.showIt(fragmentName + ":rememberSwitch is OFF");
                // switchStatus.setText("Switch is currently OFF");
            }

        }
    });

    // check the current state before we display the screen
    if (rememberSwitch.isChecked()) {
        BT_debugger.showIt(fragmentName + ":rememberSwitch is ON");
        // switchStatus.setText("Switch is currently ON");
        //voucherTextfieldEditText.setText(pass);
        if (voucherTextfieldEditText!=null) {
            //voucherTextfieldEditText.setText(sharedPreferences.getString(pass, ""));
        }

        if (pass != null) {

            String textfield = sharedpreferences.getString("PASS", pass);
            //voucherTextfieldEditText.setText(sharedPreferences.getString("PASS", pass));
            voucherTextfieldEditText.setText(textfield);
        }
    }
    else {
        BT_debugger.showIt(fragmentName + ":rememberSwitch is OFF");
        // switchStatus.setText("Switch is currently OFF");
    }

    //
    // submit click listener..

    submitButton = (Button) thisScreensView.findViewById(R.id.submitButtonVoucher);
    submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            launchScreen(voucherTextfieldEditText.getText().toString());
        }

    });

    // return the layout file as the view for this screen..
    return thisScreensView;

}// onCreateView...
```

Then I set the shared preferences string "PASS" with this line of code:

```
if (loadScreenNickname.length() > 1 && !loadScreenNickname.equalsIgnoreCase("none")) {

                // before we launch the next screen...
                if (!rememberSwitch.isChecked()) {
                    voucherTextfieldEditText.setText("");
                }

                if (rememberSwitch.isChecked()){
                    //voucherTextfieldEditText.setText("");

                    //editor.putString(pass, voucherTextfieldEditText.getText().toString().trim());
                    //editor.apply();

                    pass = voucherTextfieldEditText.getText().toString();



                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
                    editor.putString("PASS", pass);
                    editor.apply();


                }
                errormessageTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                errormessageTextView.invalidate();

                //loadScreenObject(null, thisScreen);
                try {
                    loadScreenWithNickname(loadScreenNickname);

                    foundIt = 1;

                } catch (Exception ex){
                    Log.e ("eTutorPrism Error", "Caught this exception " + ex);
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            }
        }
```

However anything I exit and restart the application, even if the remember me button is checked, it doesn't remember the previous value and the app ends up crashing due to a null. Everything else in the code works except the Remember Me. If anyones got any ideas I could use them?

Comment: Where do you initializing your sharedpreferences . And also please share your logcat error

Comment: This is the logcat error I receive with testing the code in the app: E/UncaughtException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.content.SharedPreferences$Editor android.content.SharedPreferences.edit()' on a null object reference
                                                                   at com.asfapp.ui.bt_plugins.AK_Voucher_access.launchScreen(AK_Voucher_access.java:297)
                                                                   at com.asfapp.ui.bt_plugins.AK_Voucher_access$2.onClick(AK_Voucher_access.java:224)

Comment: Ok so here is a new problem i've run into now. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46202780/sharedpreferences-in-android-app-for-remember-me-button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not initializing your `sharedPreference`. try to initialize it.

```
 SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences("myPref",MODE_PRIVATE);
```